How can I make Codeium in VScode suggest me autocompletions after a specific amount of time, e.g. 5 seconds?
Codeium is a VScode extension which I use in React for autocompletion & suggestions. The problem is that it's suggesting too soon for my preferences. Is there a way to configure it?
I tried finding a "script" to put it in the settings.json but nothing seemed to match.
